# Unable to import a module (struct) from the same folder

Tags: rust

I have 2 files: lib.rs and user.rs

**user.rs:**

```
struct User { .... }
```

and **lib.rs**:

```
use User; //  unresolved import `User`
```

Whatever I tried it hasn't panned out, for example:

```
use self::User; //  unresolved import `User`
use super::User;
```

Comment: Have you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html) chapter on modules?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to declare the `user` module in `lib.rs` first, and then import the structure from it:

```
mod user;

use user::User;
```

It is important that `user` in `mod user` coincide with `user` in `user.rs` file name.

Rust module system can be confusing for novices in the language; you really should read the [official documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html) on this.